# Testcafe hook into Rancher selenium grid

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, rancher, testcafe

Currently I'm having difficulty hooking into our Rancher selenium/node-chrome containers. I’ve tried every testcafe-browser-provider listed on npm including testcafe-browser-provider-selenium. Any insight would be appreciated since I feel I’ve exhausted every idea.

> Server started on port 3000
>   F---F.{ Error: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
    - 4444:4444/tcp
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  hub-lb:
    image: rancher/lb-service-haproxy:v0.9.6
    ports:
    - 4001:4001/tcp
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.agent.role: environmentAdmin,agent
      io.rancher.container.agent_service.drain_provider: 'true'
      io.rancher.container.create_agent: 'true'
      io.rancher.scheduler.global: 'true'

rancher-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  hub:
    retain_ip: true
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
    health_check:
      healthy_threshold: 2
      response_timeout: 5000
      port: 4444
      unhealthy_threshold: 3
      interval: 5000
      strategy: recreate
      request_line: GET / HTTP/1.0
  chrome:
    scale: 2
    start_on_create: true
  firefox:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
  hub-lb:
    start_on_create: true
    lb_config:
      certs: []
      port_rules:
      - protocol: http
        service: hub
        source_port: 4001
        target_port: 4444
    health_check:
      healthy_threshold: 2
      response_timeout: 2000
      port: 42
      unhealthy_threshold: 3
      strategy: recreate
```

Comment: Would you please clarify which host folder you map in the `:/tests` docker container directory? This can be related to a docker folder access restriction: if you are using the Docker Toolbox, note that Docker containers can only access the C:\Users directory.